# Wall not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, wall

When I use `echo "hi" | wall` on a device I have running Ubuntu 14.04 I get back:

```
Broadcast Message from rescue@ws1-/share/locale-langpack/en_CA.UTF-8.utf8/LC_ID
        (/dev/pts/2) at 14:19 ...                                              

hi
```

But when I run the same command on my desktop running Ubuntu 16.04 I get back nothing.

Permissions for Wall:

```
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root tty 27368 Jun 14 17:51 /usr/bin/wall
```

Results of `tty`:

```
/dev/pts/5
```

Results of `w`:

```
 12:56:21 up  2:40,  1 user,  load average: 0.66, 0.65, 0.79
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
philip   tty7     :0               10:17    2:39m  1:47   2.35s i3
```

Why wouldn't this be working, how can I debug the issue?

---

Also tried `echo hi > /tmp/msg && sudo wall /tmp/msg`

*Normally using `i3` but I also tried logging out and back in with unity and got the same results.*

Comment: It's not just a case of using sudo?

Comment: @RamanSailopal same results with sudo

Comment: On your problematic system, run the `tty` and `w` commands. Is your tty listed? You may be using a terminal program that doesn't update the logged-in user list `utmp`. Try running `xterm` and see if wall writes to that window.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick it shows on `xterm` I'm using `i3` will update question with results of `w` and `tty`.

Comment: How about `sudo w` ?

Comment: @林果皞 same output with `sudo w`

Comment: Are you using gnome and login as usual (since you're using classic `xterm` instead of `gnome-terminal` or other) ? How come `pts/5` output from `tty` not listed in `w` ? Are both of the commands run in the same terminal emulator ?

Comment: @林果皞 I use the default ubuntu login and select `i3`. Would that be `gnome-terminal`? As for the `tty` I ran the `w` command 2 hours after my original post, I don't remember if I restarted. Now I get `pts/0`.

Comment: @林果皞 but now when I run `w` I still get `tty/7`, I guess that's strange that it doesn't show the same `tty`? Maybe related to why `wall` doesn't work?

Comment: what if you switch to other tty by `Ctrl+Shift+F5` then run `wall hello`, will message display in both xterm and tty5 ? Also you can do `dpkg -S $(which wall)` to find out the package name(e.g. `bsdutils`), then run `apt source bsdutils` to get the source, `find . -iname '*wall*'` to figure out the `wall.c` path, then add some debug line in that file, and then in  parent directory do `./configure` and `make wall` to build and run `./wall` debug. (or `-g3`, `gdb` something)

Comment: sorry my typo, is ctrl+alt+f5, not shift

Comment: @林果皞 I was able to switch with `Ctrl+Shift+F5` but the same shortcut wasn't working to switch back. So I had to log out which closed the first tty.

Comment: will message display in tty5 if you run `wall` in tty5 ?

Comment: @林果皞 ah I see I need `F7` for `tty7` and `F5` for `tty5`?

Comment: It shows in tty5 but not tty7

Comment: `apt source bsdutils` returns `E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`

Comment: `apt-cache policy bsdutils` to figure out the installed(or other if still failed) repo link which also occur in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then `sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list` and duplicated the relevant `deb` line match with that repo link with prefix `deb-src`, then `sudo apt-get update`, then `apt source bsdutils` again.